# Turn a vector into a state...a la multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

So here is the problem...

I have a vector of values, say:

```
x = [0,4,2,0]
```

And a possible range of values corresponding to each x:

```
0: 0-9
4: 0-9
2: 0-5
0: 0-1
```

Which means the state space is: `10*10*6*2`

And I need a function, calculate state, that comes up with a unique integer value within the state space for the particular vector.  For instance:

```
calc_state(x) -> (10*6*2)*0 + (6*2)*4 + (2)*2 + (1)*0
```

And my question is: is that the correct formula?  Or am I working too small?  I feel like there should be another factor of 10 in there...but as I write this out, I'm feeling more confident it is correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that works. The extra factor of 10 comes from maxing out all the vector entries, in which case the result comes out to `10*10*6*2 - 1`.

Comment: Yeah...3 day programming marathon.  Caught this bug where I was multiplying the corresponding vector number by its own range * previous ranges...brain dead =)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. the strides property can help writing `call_state(x)` :

```
space=arange(10*10*6*2).reshape(10,10,6,2)
def call_state(x): return (x*space.strides).sum()
```